# what is the best way to partially modify anchor href in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im working on a piece of code to modify a dynamic anchor `href` in javascript. I've seen posts that suggest to `.replace()` the href completely. i was looking for a way to add extra `page` to the path as shown below.

**original url:**
`http://localhost:8000/2`

**change to:**
`http://localhost:8000/page/2`

**HTML markup (laravel):**

```
{% if posts.lastPage > 1 %}
<ul class="pagination">
    {% if posts.currentPage > 1 %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage-1) }) }}"aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% for page in 1..posts.lastPage %}
    <li class="{{ posts.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}">
        <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if posts.lastPage > posts.currentPage %}
    <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage+1) }) }}" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
    </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.pagination').on( 'click', 'a', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var postUrl = $(this).attr("href"); --> need to modify href path
    var post = "default ";
    post=  $.ajax({type: "GET", url: postUrl, async: false}).responseText;
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = post;
});
```

**note:**I have seen examples of using `regex` and `split()` used in `window.location.href`. is it possible to use `regex` or `split()` in `href`?

thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use regex of split? It is simply a string. Maybe use `url.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/') + '/page/' + url.split('/').pop()` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just change the `href` property?

```
var postUrl = $(this).attr("href"); //get
$(this).attr("href",newUrl); //set
```

To build the new URL, you could use regexp, but it will depend on your URL structure. Based on your example, you could do something like:

```
  var newUrl = postUrl.replace(/((http|https):\/\/.+?\/)(.)/,"$1page/$3");
```

Explanation:

```
/                        Starts the regexp (note that this is not a string and it's delimited by /--it could be a string, too, tho)
    (                    Starts a new group, so we can use the match in the replacement
        (http|https)     Matches the strings http or https (just in case if the protocol may vary). It is also a group as is between brackets
        :\/\/            Must be followed by :// (the / are escaped with \)
        .                Can be followed by any character
        +?               This means that the previous element (the dot) must appear at least once and the ? makes it not greedy, matching the minimum number of time (otherwise it will match everything until the end of the string)
        \/               Followed by / (again, escaped)
    )                    End the group
    (                    Starts new group to match what is after http://localhost.../
        .                Matches anything
    )                    Ends the group
/                        End the expression
```

Then in the replacement

```
$1                       Inserts the first group, the first ( )
page/                    Followed by the string "page/"
$3                       Followed the third group
```

The second group is the http|https, we don't need it because it's already inside the first group.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could provide a link to a document on `regex` if you know of a good one

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp and I'll add an explanation of the example.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `replace` for example:

```
var href =  $(this).attr("href");
href.replace(/(\/[0-9]+?)$/g, "/page$1");
```